# How to avoid MySQL 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a innoDB table which records online users. It gets updated on every page refresh by a user to keep track of which pages they are on and their last access date to the site. I then have a cron that runs every 15 minutes to DELETE old records.

I got a 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction' for about 5 minutes last night and it appears to be when running INSERTs into this table. Can someone suggest how to avoid this error?

=== EDIT ===

Here are the queries that are running:

**First Visit to site:**

```
INSERT INTO onlineusers SET
ip = 123.456.789.123,
datetime = now(),
userid = 321,
page = '/thispage',
area = 'thisarea',
type = 3
```

**On each page refresh:**

```
UPDATE onlineusers SET
ips = 123.456.789.123,
datetime = now(),
userid = 321,
page = '/thispage',
area = 'thisarea',
type = 3
WHERE id = 888
```

**Cron every 15 minutes:**

```
DELETE FROM onlineusers WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND
```

It then does some counts to log some stats (ie: members online, visitors online).

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about the table structure? Are there any clustered or nonclustered indexes?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-deadlocks.html - Running "show engine innodb status" would provide useful diagnostics.

Comment: How does inserting a single row cause a deadlock for that insert? I was expecting that within a transaction, you need to attempt to acquire at least two locks to deadlock. Inserting a single row only holds one lock. I think you are missing some inserts or selects from your first query.

Answer (score 371, accepted):

One easy trick that can help with most deadlocks is sorting the operations in a specific order.

You get a deadlock when two transactions are trying to lock two locks at opposite orders, ie:

- connection 1: locks key(1), locks key(2);
- connection 2: locks key(2), locks key(1);

If both run at the same time, connection 1 will lock key(1), connection 2 will lock key(2) and each connection will wait for the other to release the key -> deadlock.

Now, if you changed your queries such that the connections would lock the keys at the same order, ie:

- connection 1: locks key(1), locks key(2);
- connection 2: locks key(**1**), locks key(**2**);

it will be impossible to get a deadlock.

So this is what I suggest:

1. Make sure you have no other queries that lock access more than one key at a time except for the delete statement. if you do (and I suspect you do), order their WHERE in (k1,k2,..kn) in ascending order.
2. Fix your delete statement to work in ascending order:

Change

```
DELETE FROM onlineusers 
WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND
```

To

```
DELETE FROM onlineusers 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT id FROM onlineusers
    WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND 
    ORDER BY id
) u;
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that MySQL documentation suggest that in case of a deadlock the client should retry automatically. you can add this logic to your client code. (Say, 3 retries on this particular error before giving up).

Comment: If I have Transaction(autocommit=false), deadlock exception thrown. Is it enough just to retry same statement.executeUpdate() or whole transaction is now gimped and should be rollbacked+rerun everything that was running in it?

Comment: if you have transactions enabled, it's all or nothing. if you had an exception of any kind it's guaranteed that the entire transaction had no effect.
in that case you would want to restart the whole thing.

Comment: A delete based on a select on a huge table is very slower than a simple delete

Comment: Thanks you so much, dude. The 'sort statements' tip fixed my dead lock issues.

Comment: @OmryYadan From what I know, in MySQL you can't select in a subquery from the same table in which you're making the UPDATE. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: Wasn't able to use this answer bc of what @artaxerxe mentioned, but http://dasunhegoda.com/1093-you-cant-specify-target-table-table_name-for-update-in-from-clause/104/ fixed it.

Comment: @artaxerxe When running an update query you can `inner join` the subquery with the table `using(id)`, then you are selecting by the subquery but updating the actual table `UPDATE mytable t INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE datetime <= NOW() ORDER BY id) t2 USING(id) SET t.datetime = NOW()`. I think the same trick can be applied to deletes `DELETE t FROM mytable t INNER JOIN (SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE datetime <= NOW() ORDER BY id) t2 USING(id)`

Comment: how sorting of the items in the delete query fixed deadlock?

Comment: It's not possible in MySQL delete and select in the same table.

Comment: DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM table ...) fails with

`OperationalError: (1093, "You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause")`

Comment: The explanation is misleading, better read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html

Comment: What can I do, if insert statement throws deadlock exception mentioned above in the question.

Answer (score 95):

Deadlock happen when two transactions wait on each other to acquire a lock. Example:

- Tx 1: lock A, then B
- Tx 2: lock B, then A

There are numerous questions and answers about deadlocks. Each time you insert/update/or delete a row, a lock is acquired. To avoid deadlock, you must then make sure that concurrent transactions don't update row in an order that could result in a deadlock. Generally speaking, **try to acquire lock always in the same order** even in different transaction (e.g. always table A first, then table B).

Another reason for deadlock in database can be **missing indexes**. When a row is inserted/update/delete, the database needs to check the relational constraints, that is, make sure the relations are consistent. To do so, the database needs to check the foreign keys in the related tables. It *might* result in other lock being acquired than the row that is modified. Be sure then to always have index on the foreign keys (and of course primary keys), otherwise it could result in a **table lock** instead of a **row lock**. If table lock happen, the lock contention is higher and the likelihood of deadlock increases.

Comment: So perhaps my problem is that the User has refreshed the page and thus triggering an UPDATE of a record at the same time the cron is trying to run a DELETE on the record.

However, im getting the error on INSERTS, so the cron wouldn't be DELETING records that have just been created. So how can a deadlock happen on a record that is yet to be inserted?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information about the table(s) and what the transactions exactly do?

Comment: I don't see how a deadlock could happen if there is only one statement per transaction. No other operations on other tables? No special foreign keys or unique constraints? No cascade delete constraints?

Comment: nope, nothing else special...I suppose its down to the nature of the usage of the table. a row is being inserted/updated every page refresh from a visitor. Around 1000+ visitors are on at any one time.

Answer (score 18):

In case someone is still struggling with this issue:

I faced similar issue where 2 requests were hitting the server at the same time. There was no situation like below:

```
T1:
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT TABLE A
    INSERT TABLE B
    END TRANSACTION

T2:
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT TABLE B
    INSERT TABLE A
    END TRANSACTION
```

So, I was puzzled why deadlock is happening.

Then I found that there was parent child relation ship between 2 tables because of foreign key. When I was inserting a record in child table, the transaction was acquiring a lock on parent table's row. Immediately after that I was trying to update the parent row which was triggering elevation of lock to EXCLUSIVE one. As 2nd concurrent transaction was already holding a SHARED lock, it was causing deadlock.

Refer to: https://blog.tekenlight.com/2019/02/21/database-deadlock-mysql.html

Comment: In my case too, it looks like the problem was a foreign key relation. Thanks1

Comment: For me the same : one table updated, with a foreign key in another table updated. I remove my contrainst key with No Action. And then, miracle, No more deadlocks ! Of course it dosn't check contrainst anymore, but it was not usable on large updated tables. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 14):

It is likely that the delete statement will affect a large fraction of the total rows in the table. Eventually this might lead to a table lock being acquired when deleting. Holding on to a lock (in this case row- or page locks) and acquiring more locks is always a deadlock risk. However I can't explain why the insert statement leads to a lock escalation - it might have to do with page splitting/adding, but someone knowing MySQL better will have to fill in there.

For a start it can be worth trying to explicitly acquire a table lock right away for the delete statement. See [LOCK TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) and [Table locking issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-locking.html).

Answer (score 6):

You might try having that `delete` job operate by first inserting the key of each row to be deleted into a temp table like this pseudocode

```
create temporary table deletetemp (userid int);

insert into deletetemp (userid)
  select userid from onlineusers where datetime <= now - interval 900 second;

delete from onlineusers where userid in (select userid from deletetemp);
```

Breaking it up like this is less efficient but it avoids the need to hold a key-range lock during the `delete`.

Also, modify your `select` queries to add a `where` clause excluding rows older than 900 seconds.  This avoids the dependency on the cron job and allows you to reschedule it to run less often.

Theory about the deadlocks: I don't have a lot of background in MySQL but here goes... The `delete` is going to hold a key-range lock for datetime, to prevent rows matching its `where` clause from being added in the middle of the transaction, and as it finds rows to delete it will attempt to acquire a lock on each page it is modifying.   The `insert` is going to acquire a lock on the page it is inserting into, and *then* attempt to acquire the key lock.   Normally the `insert` will wait patiently for that key lock to open up but this will deadlock if the `delete` tries to lock the same page the `insert` is using because the`delete` needs that page lock and the `insert` needs that key lock.  This doesn't seem right for inserts though, the `delete` and `insert` are using datetime ranges that don't overlap so maybe something else is going on.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-next-key-locking.html

Answer (score 4):

For Java programmers using Spring, I've avoided this problem using an AOP aspect that automatically retries transactions that run into transient deadlocks.

See [@RetryTransaction](http://archiecobbs.github.io/dellroad-stuff/site/apidocs/index.html?org/dellroad/stuff/spring/RetryTransaction.html) Javadoc for more info.

Answer (score 3):

I have a method, the internals of which are wrapped in a MySqlTransaction.

The deadlock issue showed up for me when I ran the same method in parallel with itself.

There was not an issue running a single instance of the method.

When I removed MySqlTransaction, I was able to run the method in parallel with itself with no issues.

Just sharing my experience, I'm not advocating anything.

Comment: got same behaviour

Answer (score 3):

@Omry Yadan's answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423921/1810962 ) can be simplified by using ORDER BY.

Change

```
DELETE FROM onlineusers 
WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND
```

to

```
DELETE FROM onlineusers 
WHERE datetime <= now() - INTERVAL 900 SECOND
ORDER BY ID
```

to keep the order in which you delete items consistent. Also if you are doing multiple inserts in a single transaction, make sure they are also always ordered by id.

According to the mysql delete documentation:

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are deleted in the order that is specified.

You can find a reference here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html

Answer (score 2):

`cron` is dangerous.  If one instance of cron fails to finish before the next is due, they are likely to fight each other.

It would be better to have a continuously running job that would delete some rows, sleep some, then repeat.

Also, `INDEX(datetime)` is very important for avoiding deadlocks.

But, if the datetime test includes more than, say, 20% of the table, the `DELETE` will do a table scan.  Smaller chunks deleted more often is a workaround.

Another reason for going with smaller chunks is to lock fewer rows.

Bottom line:

- `INDEX(datetime)`
- Continually running task -- delete, sleep a minute, repeat.
- To make sure that the above task has not died, have a cron job whose sole purpose is to restart it upon failure.

Other deletion techniques:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig