# Unknown error: MySQLTransactionRollbackException 1213

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, transactions

I getting the exception MySQLTransactionRollbackException (error 1213) when I try to do a select query.

The exception has the following message:

> "Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

How can I restart transaction in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-transa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using innoDB and you are having issues with row level locking.

look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/innodb-lock-modes.html