# How do I avoid MySql deadlocks?

Tags: mysql, database-deadlocks, jooq, batch-insert

I'm talking to a MySql database using the [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org) database abstraction layer.

I keep getting the following error:

```
SQL [null]; Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

This is during a bulk insert of about 500 rows into a table.  It is likely that more than one of these bulk inserts will be attempted at a time from different threads.

What is causing the deadlock, and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Without more info impossible to answer. Also possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A traditional deadlock is when a transaction is trying to lock A and then B where another is trying to lock B and then A, leading to a situation where neither can complete. MySQL produces another sort of deadlock when there are too many pending locks on a particular resource.

You should check `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see how many "waiting for lock" processes you have. It could be that the ones that fail are simply out of luck because there's too many in line.

Comment: "show processlist" lists 15 processes right now, what is the limit?

Comment: If they're all locking the same table, then you've probably found the limit. I'm not sure it's documented or adjustable. You can adjust the `table_lock_wait_timeout` or `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` server variables to make the locks more patient, too.