# Deadlock in ORM when using OpenJPA

Tags: java, jpa, orm, deadlock, openjpa

I am getting a deadlock when performing the load testing with `Soap UI` running 10 every thread makes 10 request to my web service which invokes the persits method of OpenJPA entity manager.

Then I am performing the single requests, all ends well, but in multithreaded environment it ends up with deadlocks.

The error I am getting is:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction {prepstmnt 12796448 UPDATE Assessment SET dateCompleted = ? WHERE id = ? [params=?, ?]} [code=1213, state=40001]
```

The method which is crashing with a deadlock is this:

```
@Override
public AssessmentKey update(AssessmentKey assessmentKey) {
    OpenJPAEntityManager openJpaEntityMgr = OpenJPAPersistence.cast(entityManager);
    for (Assessment assessment : assessmentKey.getAssessments()) {
        if (!entityManager.contains(assessment) && !openJpaEntityMgr.isDetached(assessment)) {
            LOGGER.debug("Persisting {}", assessment);
            entityManager.persist(assessment);
        }
    }
    return entityManager.merge(assessmentKey);
}
```

`Assessment` is an entity of OpenJPA, it is just a normal entity containing JPA annotations.
If you'll need the code of it, ask for it.

I understood how deadlocks happening, how to solve them is mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans). But how to solve them in ORM I am not able to find an answer.

My `persistence.xml` file looks like this:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="com.groupgti.esb.online.tests">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>com.groupgti.esb.assessments.model.jpaimpl.Assessment</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="slf4j"/>
            <property name="openjpa.DataCache" value="false"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ReadLockLevel" value="none"/>
            <property name="openjpa.WriteLockLevel" value="pessimistic-write"/>
            <property name="openjpa.LockTimeout" value="10000"/>
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="unsupported"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Whole application uses `Spring` and the classes in which transactions are done is marked `@Transactional`. How to solve this deadlock issue in ORM?

**EDIT:**

The `AssessmentKey` has a relation to `Assessment`:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy = "assessmentKey")
private List<Assessment> assessments = new ArrayList<Assessment>();
```

And in the `Assessment` `AssessmentKey` looks like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@Index
@Column(nullable = false)
@ForeignKey
private AssessmentKey assessmentKey;
```

Comment: @Could you post `O/R` relationship of `AssessmentKey ` and `Assessment`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AssessmentKey` and `Assessment` are `OneToMany` bidirectional relationship.Both of `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` annotations have `CascadeType.PERSIST` and others.

**Point is :**

when `EntityManager` persist `Assessment`, `AssessmentKey` would persisted also. You should need to persist or merge `AssessmentKey` again.

Let me suggest OR Mapping as follow :

AssessmentKey.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}, 
           mappedBy = "assessmentKey", orphanRemoval=true)
private List<Assessment> assessments;
```

Assessment.java

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "ASSESSMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private AssessmentKey assessmentKey;
```

DB Operation

```
@Override
public AssessmentKey update(AssessmentKey assessmentKey) {
    OpenJPAEntityManager openJpaEntityMgr = OpenJPAPersistence.cast(entityManager);
    // there may be your operation
    return entityManager.merge(assessmentKey);
}
```

I assume, `Assessment` values of current `AssessmentKey` object may be as below

```
On System                               |   In Existing Database
ID      Description                     |   ID      Descrition
1001    AAA         => No Changes       |   1001    AAA
1002    BBB         => Need to update   |   1002    BB
null    DDD         => Need to add      |   1003    CCC     => need to remove.
```

When EntityManager merge `AssessmentKey`, the `EntityManager` will does the all of the process for `Assessment` as I mention in above data structure.

**Note :** make sure `orphanRemoval=true` in `OneToMany` annotation.