# Hook available for automatic retry after deadlock in django and mysql setup

Tags: mysql, django, mysql-python

I am using innoDB table in Django with mysql database. During investigation of error

> OperationalError: (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423921/1026861) from [Omry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1930838/omry-yadan). In last part of the answer he suggests

> the client should retry automatically.

I am trying to put this logic in code but at the same time is there any hook directly available in django. So that we can set 3 time automate retry in case of deadlock. Also if anyone can give example of putting this logic in code (I'm using django filters).

PS: I could have asked this below Omry's answer but I'm below 50 points and also wanted to bring it to the django experts.

Comment: What code are you executing and where is it in your django project?

Comment: Hi Timmy thanks for taking a look. I use django_auth_ldap to sync my LDAP server with my database. During one of manage_user call(to create/delete/update user details), I make ldap_backend.populate_user(<email>) [this is to sync all LDAP groups with django auth_user_groups]. This makes mysql to go into deadlock.

Answer (score 10):

This is an old question but since nobody posted an answer, here it is.

In order to retry queries if a deadlock happens, what I did was I monkey patched the method "execute" of django's CursorWrapper class. This method is called whenever a query is made, so it will work across the entire ORM and you won't have to worry about deadlocks across your project:

```
import django.db.backends.utils
from django.db import OperationalError
import time

original = django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper.execute

def execute_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    attempts = 0
    while attempts < 3:
        try:
            return original(*args, **kwargs)
        except OperationalError as e:
            code = e.args[0]
            if attempts == 2 or code != 1213:
                raise e
            attempts += 1
            time.sleep(0.2)

django.db.backends.utils.CursorWrapper.execute = execute_wrapper
```

What the code above does is: it will try running the query and if an OperationalError is thrown with the error code 1213 (a deadlock), it will wait for 200 ms and try again. It will do this 3 times and if after 3 times the problem was not solved, the original exception is raised.

This code should be executed when the django project is being loaded into memory and so a good place to put it is in the `__init__.py` file of any of your apps (I placed in the `__init__.py` file of my project's main directory - the one that has the same name as your django project).

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm using something similar to fix `OperationalError: (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')`, bur instead of doing my own wrapping code, I'm using [`retry`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry):

Comment: Yes. This solution is working fine. Now we are seeing the following error. OperationalError: (1305, 'SAVEPOINT s139806324311104_x9 does not exist').  My transaction is atomic in my views.py.  Can somebody help to resolve this issue ?