# Deadlock with identical queries

Tags: mysql, innodb, deadlock

I'm trying to resolve an error involving deadlocks on one of our busy tables. I've read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans) about deadlocks and while it makes sense, the query order doesn't seem to be the cause in my case.

Here's the abbreviated output of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`:

```
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1 2611184895, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 17501, OS thread id 140516779579136 starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 368, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 211935717, query id 3146186174 [SERVER A] Searching rows for update

UPDATE images_unread_comments
    SET unread = 0
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND comment_id IN(1,2,3) AND unread = 1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 404976 n bits 632 index `users_unread_comments` of table images_unread_comments trx id 1 2611184895 lock_mode X waiting
Record lock, heap no 558 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67d888; asc    g  ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 1 2611184892, ACTIVE 0 sec, process no 17501, OS thread id 140516774520576 updating or deleting, thread declared inside InnoDB 494
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
6 lock struct(s), heap size 1216, 11 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 211935715, query id 3146186169 [SERVER B] Updating

UPDATE images_unread_comments
    SET unread = 0
    WHERE user_id = 1 AND comment_id IN(1,2,3) AND unread = 1
    *** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 404976 n bits 632 index users_unread_comments of table images_unread_comments trx id 1 2611184892 lock_mode X
Record lock, heap no 1 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 1; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 73757072656d756d; asc supremum;;

Record lock, heap no 555 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67daf0; asc    g  ;;

Record lock, heap no 556 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67dadb; asc    g  ;;

Record lock, heap no 557 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67d940; asc    g @;;

Record lock, heap no 558 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67d888; asc    g  ;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 0 page no 404976 n bits 632 index users_unread_comments of table images_unread_comments trx id 1 2611184892 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 558 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len 4; hex 0001461a; asc   F ;; 1: len 1; hex 01; asc  ;; 2: len 6; hex 00000e67d888; asc    g  ;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
```

The thing I noticed is that the two SQL statements are identical; however one is being executed on Server A and the other on Server B. Regardless of why that is happening - why would this create a deadlock if both queries lock the same keys in the same order? Or am I misunderstanding the casue of deadlocks in the first place?

Comment: It is likely that another query which runs before this one (in one or both threads) has locked some rows. Also you cut the status report a bit short - what is the second transaction waiting for and which lock is it holding?

Comment: @Vatev I've added the rest of that section to the output.

Comment: I should of noticed this the 1-st time... The locks are on another table (images_unread_comments). Are there any triggers or foreign keys related to the 2 tables?

Comment: @Vatev no that's my mistake when shortening the table names, they should all read `images_unread_comments`. Sorry..

Answer (score 0):

It seems that transaction 1 has performed another operation (insert?) in which it locked a gap in the index. It than waits for transaction 2 to perform the update, since 2 has locked the record with ID 1. Transaction 2 however can not proceed because transaction 1 holds a lock on the index. If you can isolate all SQL statements that are used in a transaction by this operation, we can see the exact reason for the deadlock