# Will NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.update wait until the transaction finishes?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jdbctemplate

I'm using the update method in NamedParamameterJdbcTempalte which implements this org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations.

I looked up the docs and the only thing I can find is "this method issues an update via a prepared statement, binding the given arguments."

I have code that looks like this

```
//Calling jdbcTemplate.update() here on Foo objects
//Calling another update on the same set of Foo objects (I know it's dump but let's just leave it as is)
```

Now my question is will the first update wait until the transaction is completed then return, or it will  just issue that request and return?
When I get to the second line, do I have any guarantee that the transaction issued by the first call to update has completely finished?

I seem to be seeing mysql deadlock once in a while and I suspect that's because the first update has not finished its job when the second one comes in.

Found this question, but the answer doesn't really answer my question.
[How to avoid mysql 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans)

Comment: The method does what it's documented to do: it executes a statement. Nothing more.

Comment: right. we know that. but when I get to the next line of code, do I have any guarantee that the first transaction has completely finished?

Comment: Which first transaction? The statement is executed in the context of the current Spring-managed transaction. I repeat: the method does what it's documented to do: it executes a statement. Nothing more. So it doesn't start a transaction, and doesn't commit a transaction either.