# Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction : @RetryTransaction

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, deadlock

I'm working on Java Spring Hibernate Project with mysql.

I'm trying to make some insert in cascade. The jobs are thrown on a cluster so they can occurs nearly at the same time and so there is a Deadlock  problem.

I have this error :

> Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans) that there is @RetryTransaction for spring developper. A way to configure [here](http://dellroad-stuff.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/publish/reports/javadoc/index.html?org/dellroad/stuff/spring/RetryTransaction.html).

They say that :

> The method's class must be woven (either at build time or runtime)
>   using the AspectJ compiler with the RetryTransactionAspect aspect
>   (included in the dellroad-stuff JAR file).

What does it mean ?

But i don't succeed to make it work. It never restart the transaction. What am i missing ?

Thanks !

```
@Override
@RetryTransaction
@Transactional
public void save(AnalyseResult analyseResult){

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    final int attempt = RetryTransactionAspect.getAttempt();

    System.out.println("#############");
    System.out.println("Retry Transact : "+attempt);
    System.out.println("#############"); 

    analyseResultDao.save(analyseResult);
}
```

In my BeanConfig.xml :

```
<bean class="org.dellroad.stuff.spring.RetryTransactionAspect" factory-method="aspectOf">
     <property name="persistenceExceptionTranslator" ref="hibernateExceptionTranslator"> </property>
    <property name="maxRetriesDefault" value="4"></property>
        <property name="initialDelayDefault" value="25"></property>
        <property name="maximumDelayDefault" value="5000"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Do you have the AspectJ JAR's on your classpath? I'm going to assume so. I'd have a look and see if there is any Hibernate documentation because I imagine that you would need to configure the Hibernate transaction manager with AspectJ.

Comment: I handle with maven Aspectjrt.1.5.4 & aspectjweaver.1.5.4. So they are in the classpath. Do you mean i have to add some config as this :<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager" /> ?