# Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Recently, I found lots of deadlock errors in my application.

```
Mysql2::Error: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction: INSERT INTO `products`....
```

the code as below:

After user has been created, I will add some products to user. I don't understand why deadlock happened.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :add_products
    has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy

    def self.create_user
      User.create!(.......)
    end

    def add_products
      Product.add(self, "product_name", 10)
    end
    .....
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    def self.add(user, product_name, amount)
       transaction do
         product = user.products.find_by_product_name(product_name)
         if product
            product.increment :amount, amount
            product.save!
         else
            product = self.create! user_id: user.id,
                                   product_name: product_name,
                                   amount: amount
         end
       end
       product
    end
end
```

I didn't find the root cause, can anyone give me some advice? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: With in add method, Why are you using self again.? Use Product instead.

Comment: You are right, I have already modified.

Comment: Please refer following link, this will help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans

Comment: @liuzxc So my comment was the answer..?

Comment: @Jyoyhu：I am not sure, can you explain why can lead to deadlock?

Comment: https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/how-to-try-again-when-exceptions-happen-in-ruby/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

My guess is that you are using InnoDB and probably doing concurrent insertions.

To trace and understand the cause, check out these articles:

- [MySQL deadlocks with concurrent inserts](http://thushw.blogspot.com/2010/11/mysql-deadlocks-with-concurrent-inserts.html)
- [How can I configure MySQL Innodb to handle 1000s of inserts per hour?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25472/how-can-i-configure-mysql-innodb-to-handle-1000s-of-inserts-per-hour)

One way to fix the issue is to retry like it is shown in the code below:

```ruby
def add_products
    retries = 0

    begin
        Product.add(self, "product_name", 10)
    rescue  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => ex
        if ex.message =~ /Deadlock found when trying to get lock/ #ex not e!!
            retries += 1   
            raise ex if retries > 3  ## max 3 retries 
            sleep 10
            retry
        else
            raise ex
        end
    end
end
```

Or, there are some gems like [transaction_retry](https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_retry) to handle MySQL deadlocks.

Comment: I have a question: save and create methods are wrapped inside a transaction, is it not necessary to add transaction to 'add' method?

Comment: Transaction is necessary if you have multiple insertions to make sure all are successful or abort. Depends totally on your implementation, but just by looking at the code you provided I'd say not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

This has saved me a lot of headaches: [transaction_retry](https://github.com/qertoip/transaction_retry) ruby gem.

From the README of the gem:

> Retries database transaction on deadlock and transaction serialization
>   errors. Supports MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite.

Comment: sorry, I know you have a high reputation on this site, but... this answer is sort of link-only and not spam. If you could throw some more light on how this would help the question, it would be appreciated

Comment: @Yasky it is a gem that deals exactly with the kind of problems the question is asking for. In a concurrence environment sometimes deadlocks are inevitable, the only way is just retry the transaction. This gem that this job automatically.

Comment: anyone have an idea that I can create tests for this case? Like, I want to simulate a deadlock and make sure this gem implementation fixes it.