# Does MySQL InnoDB locks multiple rows with READ_COMMITTED isolation level?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb, rowlocking, read-committed

I am in trouble while resolving `LOCK WAIT TIMEOUT EXCEED` error with MySQL InnoDB.

I have gone through [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/08/28/differences-between-read-committed-and-repeatable-read-transaction-isolation-levels) and it says if we use isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` then my update query should lock only those rows which match the `WHERE` condition, but this is not working for me as I am getting `54` row locks for that query.

The result of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` is given below.

```
---TRANSACTION 8AE162608, ACTIVE 102 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 56 lock struct(s), heap size 6960, 54 row lock(s), undo log entries 135
MySQL thread id 18013536, query id 164766412915 localhost MyDataDb Updating
update stock set quantity = quantity + -1, last_updated_dts='2015-01-19 00:08:23', last_updated_by='vishal' where location = 1 and product_id = '123'
------- TRX HAS BEEN WAITING 98 SEC FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
```

Why I am getting **54** row locked while my update query condition matches only **one row** and I am using **`READ_COMMITED`** isolation level?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` has a promise: the database promises to only read committed data and **keep not-yet-committed data out of the transaction**.

The lock timeout error is a runtime-error: the database tries to update data but it cannot find a good moment to do so (see the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` mentioned [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html) in the MySQL reference manual). Even if there is no data for modifying, the database needs to find a moment in time to assert that.

The transaction isolation level `READ_COMMITTED` already improves the database's chances of finding a good moment to update data (see [here](http://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/) for example), but it cannot prevent other queries/transactions from locking the entire table (full table scan like your culprit query probably does).

Some more searching does show a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2423921/3080094) for your delete problem.