# "Deadlock found when trying to get lock" error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I am using franzose/ClosureTable for managing directories file structure. The following issue occurred when I tried to add multiple child one by one with multiple request at a time.

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: `INSERT INTO resource_closure (ancestor, descendant, depth) SELECT tbl.ancestor, 7801, tbl.depth+1 FROM resource_closure AS tbl WHERE tbl.descendant = 7801 UNION ALL SELECT 7801, 7801, 0` ) in file `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php` on line number 625

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2423921/2815635

Comment: @jotik this is the complete message :- SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction (SQL: 
            INSERT INTO resource_closure (ancestor, descendant, depth)
            SELECT tbl.ancestor, 7801, tbl.depth+1
            FROM resource_closure AS tbl
            WHERE tbl.descendant = 7801
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 7801, 7801, 0
        ) in file \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line number 625

Comment: @Rishi i have checked the link u provided but i don't now how to resolve it in the package m using "franzose/ClosureTable"