# Why is this mysql deadlock occurring?

Tags: php, mysql, deadlock

Here's two pretty simple mysql statements (that happen in this order). For some reason, the second transaction often deadlocks. Does anyone have any idea why?

```
$query = "
        DELETE FROM queues
        WHERE   queuetype='autoresponder'
        AND recipient={$subscriberid}
    ";
    $this->Db->Query($query);

    $query = "
        INSERT INTO queues (queueid, queuetype, ownerid, recipient, processed)

        SELECT  queueid, 'autoresponder', ownerid, {$subscriberid}, 0
        FROM    autoresponders
        WHERE   listid={$listid}
        AND active<>0
    ";
    $status = $this->Db->Query($query);
```

Both tables have numerous indexes...
[image]
Does anyone have any idea why, when the two transactions are executed separately, the deadlock occurs on the second Query()?

For reference, here's the select explained...[image]

Comment: What is the performance like on the select statement on it's own? And the delete?

Comment: Great, like 0.006s.

Comment: See if you can find any answer from this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans?rq=1