# Deadlock error in inserting bulk of records to MySQL database using trigger and Qt multi threading

Tags: mysql, qt, deadlock

I have a multi thread program (In this case in Qt) which every thread at a specific time, writes 500 records in a `MySQL` table (I call that as `A_tbl`) and also there is a trigger that inserts some values to other tables (I call them as `B_tbl`) and after that by some `select` queries in the trigger, I get the `ID`s of those inserted records in `B_tbl`.

But these `select` queries lead to this error:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction QMYSQL3: Unable to execute statement
```

This is my trigger:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `IpAn`.`A_tbl_BEFORE_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT ON `A_tbl` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT IGNORE INTO source_names (source_name) VALUES (NEW.source_name);
INSERT IGNORE INTO locations (loc1,loc2) VALUES (loc1,loc2);

SET @source_names_id = (select id from source_names USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where source_name=NEW.source_name);
SET @locations_id = (select id from locations USE INDEX (PRIMARY) where loc1=NEW.loc1 and loc2=NEW.loc2);

...

END
```

If I change the threads to one, the error will not occur.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid mysql 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans)

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks, I saw that question before but if you read that  carefully you see that my question is differ. The identical part is just existence of `Deadlock`.

Comment: You could also try asking this question on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I also asked my question there.