# Avoid Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction on MariaDB (MySQL) INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-deadlocks

I have a simple table with a bunch of rows. There are no foreign keys. There is one unique key on several of the columns.

Here is an example of the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO das_args (a,b,c,d) VALUES (1,2,3,4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE VALUES(1,2,3,4)
```

The unique key is (a,b,c).

The error is:

```
(1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction')
```

I've read [How to avoid mysql 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans) which is an excellent discussion of the same error message being triggered with a different use case.

Autocommit is true. This is the only statement. There is no BEGIN or COMMIT.

I don't see a way that I can refactor this. There are simply two clients that appear to be updating the same unique key at the same time (which shouldn't happen, but does). My code just re-runs the statement and it succeeds, but I would like to remove the deadlock errors.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would expect the syntax to be

```
INSERT INTO das_args (a,b,c,d)
    VALUES (1,2,3,4)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  d = VALUES(d);
```

As for the deadlock -- It sounds like there is more than the one statement in the transaction.  Let's see the `BEGIN` through the `COMMIT`.

What is the value of `autocommit`?

Comment: Auto commit is true. This is the only statement. There is no begin or commit.

Comment: With `UNIQUE(a,b,c)`, I am surprised that you could get a deadlock.  Please provide the "Latest Deadlock" part of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`

Comment: I'm surprised too! I'll get the output.