# Uncaught TYPO3 Exception

Tags: typo3

I have an error that occurs in TYPO3 8.7.27.

> "An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE tags2, cache1 FROM cf_cache_pages_tags AS tags1 JOIN cf_cache_pages_tags AS tags2 ON tags1.identifier = tags2.identifier JOIN cf_cache_pages AS cache1 ON tags1.identifier = cache1.identifier WHERE tags1.tag IN ('pageId_1')': Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

I don't know how it occurs and how to resolve this issue.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid mysql 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332768/how-to-avoid-mysql-deadlock-found-when-trying-to-get-lock-try-restarting-trans)

Comment: Have you tried to execute the Database analyzer and cleared all caches in Install Tool?

Comment: How did you get to this error? Frontend / Backend / Clearing Cache / Translating Record?

Comment: @nito I had a query like that when I sorted pages by drag and drop in the pagetree in backend.