# MySql | Insert Statement | Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I came across the situation where deadlock was found while inserting the records in the child table.

**Let me explain the scenario in detail**

### I am having two tables

**1. table_a** | (parent table)

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table_a | ID | PRIMARY_KEY |
| table_a | NAME | - |
| table_a | DESCRIPTION | - |

**2. table_b** (child table)

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| table_b | ID | PRIMARY_KEY |
| table_b | NAME | - |
| table_b | VALUE | - |
| table_b | REF_ID | FOREIGN_KEY (from table_a ID) |

**Below are the steps that I am following to insert records:**

1. Begin Transaction; (auto commit is disabled)
2. INSERT INTO table_a;
3. Preparing required objects
4. INSERT INTO table_b;
5. COMMIT/ROLLABACK Transaction;

While reaching at **step 4 :**

"Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Query being executed when exception was thrown:
INSERT INTO table_b  (NAME, VALUE, REF_ID) VALUES ("TEST", 'TEST_VALUE', 10)
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
Query being executed when exception was thrown:
INSERT INTO table_b  (NAME, VALUE, REF_ID) VALUES ("TEST", 'TEST_VALUE', 10)"

**Note** : I am not doing any other alter operation on the same row.

**ISOLATION_LEVEL : REPEATABLE-READ**

Please let me know, if any other information are needed. I will update the question as per the request.

Comment: See if this post helps you out with your Deadlock issue [Stack Post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2332768/15405352)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, But my use case different.

Comment: why the isolation_level is repeatable-read is it on purpose as this might cause problems,you should use read-committed and also create an index for ref_id column in table_b as this is needed in case you update the parent rows.

Comment: We have created the index for ref_id column, let me update the question.